# Why uicollectionview ui update not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to implement the function of automatically uploading uicollectionview when I receive data.
Now my code works normally at pull-to-refresh.(Data update and ui update)
However, when a function is called by the subview button in the uicollectionview cell, the data is updated successfully, but the view is not updated.

There's my code below.
First

```
@objc func test_func()
    {
        let alert=UIAlertController(title: "Some title", message: "\(self.engineerName.text!) Some message body", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                AccessController().work_end(number: (self.number.text)!)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

A function code called from the button, a subview of the collectionview cell.
If you press OK in modal, the following function is called by the complete handler.

```
@objc func work_end(number:String)
    {
        AF.request(API_Server_info().ServerIP+"/api/access", method: .put, parameters: ["number":number], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
            self.get_list_data()
        }
    }
```

Then the following function is executed, which sends data to the put method to the server and requests the entire data again when the results return normally.

```
class AccessController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    private var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    let MainView = UIView()

    lazy var alc:AccessList = {
        let launcher = AccessList()
        launcher.accesslistcontroller = self
        return launcher
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Setup()

        get_list_data()
    }

    @objc func get_list_data(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            AF.request(API_Server_info().ServerIP+"/api/access/customer/all/1", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil)
                .validate().responseJSON { (response) in
                    let result = JSON(response.value!)
                    self.alc.AccessListData = []
                    for i in result
                    {
                        self.alc.AccessListData.insert(AccessListClass(engineerName: i.1["engineerName"].stringValue, engineerCompany: i.1["engineerCompany"].stringValue, end: i.1["end"].stringValue, engineerPhone: i.1["engineerPhone"].stringValue, number: i.1["number"].stringValue, engineerGrade: i.1["engineerGrade"].stringValue, customerManager: i.1["customerManager"].stringValue, title: i.1["title"].stringValue, name: i.1["name"].stringValue, customerName: i.1["customerName"].stringValue, content: i.1["content"].stringValue, start: i.1["start"].stringValue, location: i.1["location"].stringValue, manager: i.1["manager"].stringValue), at: self.alc.AccessListData.count)
                    }
                    self.alc.collectionView.reloadData()
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func work_end(number:String)
    {
            AF.request(API_Server_info().ServerIP+"/api/access", method: .put, parameters: ["number":number], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
                self.get_list_data()
            }
    }

    func Setup(){
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(MainView)
        MainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        MainView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive=true
        MainView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive=true
        MainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
        MainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true

        MainView.addSubview(alc.collectionView)
        alc.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        alc.collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: MainView.leftAnchor).isActive=true
        alc.collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: MainView.rightAnchor).isActive=true
        alc.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: MainView.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
        alc.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: MainView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true

        self.alc.collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(get_list_data), for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

I ran the code inside DispatchQueue.main.async, but it didn't work in the direction I wanted.
I tried various methods, but my knowledge limit made it impossible to solve through search, so I asked a question in the stackoverflow.
Thanks.

P.S. This question can be written with the help of a web translator, so please understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reload of the collectionview should come inside dispatchQueue.main...... not the API call.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.alc.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: The problem has been resolved.
You do not call a function directly from the Button event, which is the subview of the CollectionView cell.
func collectionView(_ collectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath) {
}
The desired result was obtained by processing within the above function.
Thank you for your answer.